# Uncaught syntax error in github deployment

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, github

I made a simple website that recommends restaurants based on your city using Zomato API. It works perfectly locally, but when I deployed on a GitHub page it gives me the following

```
POST https://devangmukherjee.github.io/locations/delhincr 405
(anonymous) @   index.js:15
```

index.js:15 - const res = await fetch(`${hostname}/locations/${query}`, {

and

```
index.js:24 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

index.js:24 is });

The repo is here - https://github.com/devangmukherjee/random-zomato-restaurant

It is a very small repo only three files.

The website link is here - https://devangmukherjee.github.io/random-zomato-restaurant/

The same code works perfectly locally. What can I do?

Comment: You’re making an API call and getting html back, which likely could mean you’re hitting some type of error. Your question needs to stand on its own; include the relevant code.

Comment: What do you mean by “deployed on a github page”? The code you link to is an Express app.

Comment: @DaveNewton your deploy your static pages on github for free similar to heroku. I have done that. and the relevant code I dont know what it is because locally this code works fine, only when I deployed it gives me this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you visit the website locally, you are running your Express backend on localhost too. But, when you visit it on GitHub, your backend isn't executing on GitHub's machines. So, when I write "Mumbai" in the search field, in the line `` const res = await fetch(`${hostname}/locations/${query}`, { `` you are actually fetching https://devangmukherjee.github.io/locations/mumbai. Since that GitHub's URL doesn't allow POST HTTP method (because your backend isn't executing there), you are getting a 405 HTTP error. Thus the first error. This response's body is HTML and not JSON. When you do `res.json()` on line 23 there is a parsing error when it finds the angle bracket of the first HTML tag. And that's the reason for your second error.

To make it work you have to deploy your backend somewhere else, e.g., [Vercel](https://vercel.com/docs/runtimes#official-runtimes/node-js) or [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2018/09/13/how-to-run-express.js-apps-with-netlify-functions/) serverless functions or [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) (among many other possibilities). And then, update your `hostname` variable on line 4 accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to go through my repo, this answer helped a lot. I deployed on heroku and it works perfectly now! :)

Comment: I'm glad I helped :)